# How can I change the default parameters in git project config file?

Tags: git

Everytime I create a new project git creates a config file in the repository directory. The values in this file doesn't work with my setup. This file overrides the properly set system and user configuration.

This problem becomes more problematic with the repo tool from Android, what creates and deletes git repos dynamically.

How can I change (even better would be remove) the values from the default config file in the repo that gets created on `git clone` and `git init`?

Comment: Did you use the `--global` flag when you set those configs?

Comment: Is there a `config` under `/usr/share/git-core/templates`?  Is `init.templateDir` specified in the global or system gitconfig?

Comment: @Matt95 No, I edited user configuration manually.

Comment: @ElpieKay no on both questions

Comment: @ElpieKay I tried to add an empty `config` in `/usr/share/git-core/templates`, but it has no effect.

Comment: Then do you have something like `export GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=foo/bar` in `~/.bashrc` or other similar files? Or do you use an alias of `git clone` or `git init` with `--template foo/bar`? I can't think of any other cases.

Comment: @ElpieKay not results for: `grep -r -e "GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR" ~` `grep -r -e "GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR" /etc` `grep -r -E "alias.*git" ~` `grep -r -E "alias.*git" /etc`

Comment: What are the settings you are trying to override?

Comment: filemode is set to true per default.